# What is the writing direction on Korean name seals?

Tags: written

We‘ve had a name seal/stamp made for an acquaintance named 규원.

When using the stamp, it comes out as 원규 (see image: https://ibb.co/5BzkV01 ). The stamp guy said this was a traditional style, but I can’t find anything about it online. A Korean friend says they don’t think that’s true.

Is the stamp wrong, should we try and get it replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stamp follows the Traditional East Asian writing order, which is in columns from top to bottom, then right to left, and this is a special case of the writing order where each column only has one character.

> [image]
>
> Random example from Google image searching **인장**. The seal says 베드로後書 ([*Second Epistle of Peter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Epistle_of_Peter)).

"Traditional" character orders can come in several varieties, however (see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/writing-direction-on-seals).

A left-to-right horizontal order is also commonly found in Korean seals, but would not be what the rest of East Asia calls "traditional" (and is rarely found outside of Korean).